# WPF: decide where to show the contentPresenter in your User control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, contentpresenter

I have a very simple UserControl with some borders and some decorations that react to mouseOver, pressed and some nice things.

I want to allow people to set the content of the text from outside, but when I set the content, the generated content presenter overwrites my whole WPF structure.

This is what I tried so far:

```
<UserControl tags tags tags>
    <!-- This is the only way I found to style the textblock that WPF -->
    <!-- generates to encapsulate the content string -->
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <TextBlock Background="Green"
                       HorizontalAligment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text = "{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>

    <!-- Here my borders and fancy things. I want to add animations -->
    <!-- and react to mouseOver and Pressed like a button -->

    <Border x:Name="SuperNiceBorder" tag tag tag>
        <HERE I WANT THE CONTENTPRESENTER>
    </Border>

</UserControl>
```

Is there a way to tell WPF I want the text set by the user in the Content just there ???

Comment: UserControl.Content = object, TextBlock.Text = string.  This will not work. Why don't you use a ContentPresenter instead of TextBlock and bind Content instead of Text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all your animations and triggers inside the ControlTemplate.

Replace your TextBlock with a ContentPresenter:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySolution.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Green">
            <ContentPresenter
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Content = "{TemplateBinding Content}"/></Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyBorder" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>

</UserControl>
```

And you can use the UserControl like these examples:

**1:**

```
    <local:MyControl Content="Test Testing tester"/>
```

**2:**

```
    <local:MyControl>
        <TextBlock Text="Another test from a TextBlock"/>
    </wpfAllPurposesTest:MyControl>
```

Comment: how do you add a trigger for is pressed ?

Comment: @javirs look at this tutorial where possible triggers are explained https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/